# Nominal attributes in arff file created by arff library in python

Tags: python, arff

The `dump` command in the arff library in Python enables the user to create an arff file according to the input given, e.g. the command:

```
arff.dump("outputDir", data, relation="relation1",
          names=['age, fatRatio, hairColor'])
```

yields the following arff:

```
@relation relation1
@attribute age real
@attribute hairColor string
@data
10,0.2,black
22,10,yellow
30,2,black
```

for the data given:

```
data = [[10,0.2,'black'],[22,10,'yellow'],[30,2,'black']]
```

My question is: How to notify the relevant mechanism that I want the `hairColor` to be a nominal attribute, i.e. I want my arff header to be as following:

```
@relation relation1
@attribute age real
@attribute hairColor **nominal**
@data
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this outlined here :

https://code.google.com/p/arff/wiki/Documentation

I think the better method for me was the second one which recommends this :

```
arff_writer = arff.Writer(fname, relation='diabetics_data', names)
arff_writer.pytypes[arff.nominal] = '{not_parasite,parasite}'
arff_writer.write([arff.nominal('parasite')])
```

If you look at the code for arff.nominal, it's defined like this :

```
class Nominal(str):
    """Use this class to wrap strings which are intended to be nominals
    and shouldn't have enclosing quote signs."""
    def __repr__(self):
        return self
```

So what I have done is created a different "wrapper" nominal class for each nominal in my attributes like this :

```
class ZipCode(str):
    """Use this class to wrap strings which are intended to be nominals
    and shouldn't have enclosing quote signs."""
    def __repr__(self):
        return self
```

and then following the code above, you can do something like this :

```
arff_writer = arff.Writer(fname, relation='neighborhood_data', names)
arff_writer.pytypes[type(myZipCodeObject)] = '{85104,84095}'
# then write out the rest of your attributes...

arff_writer.write([arff.nominal('parasite')])
```